# How to center the text on vuetify footer?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i am trying to create a Vuetify footer and i am running into some issues. I have made a Codepen here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYazWv.

I am new to vuetify so i'm trying to see how i can put the title in the center and push the checkbox to the right along with the buttons with using too many 
spacers

I am following the official vuetify docs https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/footer

```
<v-footer
  height="auto"
  color="primary lighten-1"
>
  <v-card class="flex flat tile"> 
    <v-card-title class="primary lighten-1">
      <v-layout justify-center row wrap>

        <strong class="subheading white--text">
        Some Random Text
      </strong>
      </v-layout>


      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
     <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

 <v-checkbox dark label="Click Me"></v-checkbox>
        <v-btn v-on:click="saveClicked">
        <v-icon>save</v-icon> Save
      </v-btn>
        <v-btn>
          <v-icon>close</v-icon> Cancel
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-title>
    </v-card>
```

The v-spacer pushes the buttons in place but doesn't seem to apply on checkbox. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `grow` class to `<v-layout>`.
2. Add `shrink` class to `<v-checkbox>`.

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/KLbbzb).

Note: to align the title to left, remove `flex` and `justify-center` classes from `<v-layout>`.